# JsonMappingException: Invalid name start character code 54 Spring Boot REST

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, rest, jackson

Recently I've been investigation one bug and faced interesting case with Spring Boot Rest API.

I have a java object which I return to the user:

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@ToString
public class TestModel {

  private List<String> valid = new ArrayList<>();

  private Map<String, String> invalid = new HashMap<>();
  
}
```

It's a simple object which returns a list of valid ids and a map which contain invalid id as a key and message why it happened as a value. Usually this map is empty or have multiple elements. And it works fine. But when this map has only one element we receive an exception:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Invalid name start character '6' (code 54) (name "627228f554e7655db21f2859"); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid name start character '6' (code 54) (name "627228f554e7655db21f2859") (through reference chain: TestModel["invalid"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap["627228f554e7655db21f2859"])
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:296)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Invalid name start character '6' (code 54) (name "627228f554e7655db21f2859")
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.util.StaxUtil.throwAsGenerationException(StaxUtil.java:51)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.ToXmlGenerator.writeString(ToXmlGenerator.java:676)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:41)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFieldsUsing(MapSerializer.java:905)
        ... 120 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Invalid name start character '6' (code 54) (name "627228f554e7655db21f2859")
        at com.fasterxml.aalto.out.XmlWriter.throwOutputError(XmlWriter.java:475)
        at com.fasterxml.aalto.out.XmlWriter.reportNwfName(XmlWriter.java:386)
        at com.fasterxml.aalto.out.ByteXmlWriter.verifyNameComponent(ByteXmlWriter.java:224)
        at com.fasterxml.aalto.out.ByteXmlWriter.constructName(ByteXmlWriter.java:170)
        at com.fasterxml.aalto.out.WNameTable.findSymbol(WNameTable.java:324)
        at com.fasterxml.aalto.out.RepairingStreamWriter._writeStartOrEmpty(RepairingStreamWriter.java:340)
        at com.fasterxml.aalto.out.RepairingStreamWriter.writeStartElement(RepairingStreamWriter.java:231)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.ToXmlGenerator.writeString(ToXmlGenerator.java:667)
```

Exception message is longer so I omitted some and put here just the main of it.

The interesting case it that I can't reproduce this issue locally. I'm running it on my mac machine and it works fine. I receive a response body in postman:

```
{
    "invalid": {
        "627228f554e7655db21f2859": "Not valid."
    }
}
```

But it fails on my environment which is docker container ubuntu java17
I've tried to update a jackson lib to the latest. Now we're using 2.10.3, but I tried the latest I found in maven repo: 2.14.1. It didn't help. I also tried to reproduce this issue on my local docker. But I couldn't. It works fine.

Maybe someone faced with such issue already?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered a similar situation where some code worked locally but didn't work when deployed on kubernetes. The problem was with regex but it might be the same cause that caused your issue. I was using a regex `[^\*\?\h]*` to check validity of some input. At some point I saw some input failed by my regex that should not have been failed. And locally it worked. So I printed out the way regex looked on kubernetes and it turned out that it was interpreted as `[^*?h]*` instead of `[^\*\?\h]*` my guess is that kubernetes itself runs on java so it interpreted regex as java string and I needed to add extra slash for double encoding for java and regex. So I changed my regex from `[^\*\?\h]*` to `[^\\*\\?\\h]*` and it worked. To my surprise it also worked locally as well.

So my guess for your problem that it somehow doesn't recognize symbol `"` within your JSON. SO you will need to replace `"` with `\"` if my guess is correct. You can do it with custom json serializer in your server side I guess

Comment: Hey, Michael! Thanks for the answer. I'll try to investigate in this direction. Seems like a pretty weird stuff to me, but since I'm out of ideas I'll try to investigate your advice.